# Проблема с указателями, или я совсем не знаю Си

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, malloc

Нужно написать что-то типа словаря. У меня есть структура L типа lista, также есть словарь - массив slowka_dnia типа slowo (N=25), я подаю свой словарь в функцию init, там для каждого элемента из slowka_dnia я вызываю функцию dopisz, в этой функции L - указатель на мою структуру и мне необходимо переписать данные из slowo s в L.s[L.n]. Да и все typedef-ы и фунцкия init были даны преподователем.

Проблема в том, что при выполнении функции dopisz, а именно строки с использованием malloc появляется ошибка.

```
typedef struct slowo {//структура с аналогом слова в одном языке и его перевод в другом
    char ang[N];
    char pol[N];
}slowo;

typedef enum sort {
    BRAK, POL_ANG, ANG_POL
}sort;

typedef struct lista {
    slowo** s;//1-мерный массив указатилей на структуру slowo
    int n;//кол-во элементов                    
    sort jak_posortowana;//как отсортирован список
}lista;

int init(lista* L, slowo* slowka_dnia, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        if (!dopisz(L, slowka_dnia[i])) return 0;

    L->jak_posortowana = BRAK;
    L->n = n;
    return 1;
}

int dopisz(lista* L, slowo s) {
    L->s[L->n] = (slowo*)malloc(sizeof(slowo));//ошибка вот тут
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) L->s[L->n]->ang[i] = s.ang[i];
    for (int i = 0;i<N; i++) L->s[L->n]->pol[i] = s.pol[i];
    L->n++;
    L->jak_posortowana = BRAK;
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Вы не написали в чем проблема

Comment: да, исправил, о самом главном забыл написать)

Comment: @koshachok На данном ресурсе не решают задачи, а помогают найти проблему в решении этой задачи. Опишите где проблема, покажите, что вы сами уже сделали. В таком виде вопрос подлежит закрытию.

Comment: @koshachok а ошибку, которая возникает при вызове malloc, мы будем угадывать телепатически

Comment: В функции dopisz у нас указатель на L, как мне корректно выделить память под L.s в таком случае или вообще не нужно выделять память, а можно просто записывать данные?

Comment: Еще поясните что должна делать функция dopisz

Comment: Называйте и переменные функции **только** английскими словами. Причём правильными.

Comment: переменные названы не мной а преподавателем, сам знаю, что на английском всё отлично понятно, а что сразу может сказать функция с названием `dopisz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь по не инициализированному указателю. В момент выполнения этой строки:

```
L->s[L->n] = (slowo*)malloc(sizeof(slowo));
```

У вас уже должна быть выделена память под хранение вашего массива указателей. Т.е. в функции `init` вы должны выполнить

```
L->s=(slowo **)malloc(sizeof(slowo *) * n);
memset(L->s,0,sizeof(slowo *) * n); // На всякий случай, malloc не гарантирует выделения очищенной памяти.
```

Это происходит потому, что объявленный в структуре `lista` `slowo **` - это не массив указателей, а всего 4(8) байт в которых должен быть адрес области памяти где будет располагаться такой массив. Т.е. это указатель на массив указателей.

**Обновление**

Вы выделяете память на n указателей, если вам в процессе работы вот этого n станет не хватать, то единственный способ решить проблему - выделить область памяти под новый, увеличенный размер, скопировать (memcpy) массив из старой области памяти в новую. освободить (free) старую область и наконец поменять L->s на адрес этой новой области. Но если это происходит часто и смотря какая дальше идет работа - вполне возможно, что массив неподходящее решение, а нужен только указатель на 1е слово и в самом слове указатель на следующее и/или предыдущее - т.е. организовывать список.

И в случае с расширяемым массивом я бы предусмотрел еще одно поле в структуре рядом с ним - количество элементов под которое выделена память. И память можно выделять не по 1 элементу, а например по степеням 2-ки. Т.е. надо хранить 3 элемента - выделяем на 4, захотели записать 5й - выделяем новую область уже на 8, т.е. чем больше массив - тем больше запас оставляем на будущее, что бы постоянно это не делать

Comment: а если в процессе нужно будет добавлять какие-то элементы в мою структуру?

Comment: сейчас с немного другой проблемкой сталкнулся, когда я в функции dopisz начинаю записывать данные в L, оно внезапно заявляет, что не может прочитать память выделенную под L->s[L->n]->ang[i].

Comment: @koshachok Если вы реально словарь делаете, то боюсь slowo у вас обрастет еще несколькими указателями. Просто поиск слов хоть в массиве хоть в списке будет долгим, если их >1k будет. Вам тогда надо будет смотреть в сторону двоичных деревьев. P.S. А по вошему последнему комментарию - отлаживайте программу, расставляйте печать данных например. Потому как я так сходу не вижу в чем может быть проблема, раз вы только что выделили память под данный элемент и `i` у вас за пределы не выходит

Comment: я бы с радостью сюда запилил нормальную структуру, но это обычный проект в универе; при выполнении  `dopisz` смотрю чему равно моё  `L->s[L->n]->ang` : `0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.>` и как понимаю, тут какая-то бага с выделением памяти произошла

Comment: @koshachok Нашел ошибку, видимо из за нее проблемы. Вы просто в dopisz обращаетесь к L->n, но когда вы выделили память под L вы наверняка ее не инициализаровали и там изначально может быть не 0. Вы в init обнулите поле. И кстати не ясно зачем вы делаете L->n++ в dopis а потом в конце init делаете L->n=n, ведите переменную где то в одном месте

Comment: `lista L = {NULL,0,BRAK}` - строка в main, т.е. n=0, а в самой dopisz делаю n++ так как ещё должна быть функция добавления элементов, кроме как объявления первичного словаря, т.е. добавляем ещё элемент и n++, а так как в init есть строка `L->n=n` у нас всё будет ок.

Comment: @koshachok А почему NULL, вы память то под L->s выделили ? И вы бы слова все таки по ссылке передавали внутрь, я понимаю что C скорее всего просто копирует эту структуру при передаче, но старые версии не давали так жестко обходится

Comment: вообще эта запись из кода препода( я думал, что в ходе выполнения нужно память выделять

Comment: @koshachok Ну да в ходе выполнения. Я просто подумал, что вы в таком виде какую то отладочную инфу распечатали и дали

Answer (score 2):

В определении `lista` написано что `lista.s` это массив указателей, а вы в `dopisz` выделяете память под одну (!) структуру `slowo` и полученный указатель присваиваете `lista.s`. То есть ваша первая ошибка в том что вы простой указатель присваиваете указателю на указатель.

Вторая проблема в том, что у вас происходит утечка памяти в строке

```
L->s[L->n] = (slowo*)malloc(sizeof(slowo));//ошибка вот тут
```

здесь вы на каждый вызов `dopisz` выделяете блок памяти под структуру `slowo` при этом ничего не делаете с блоками которые выделяли на предыдущих вызовах `dopisz`. Эта память уходит в фонд поддержки голодающих Африки и не возвращается!

Теперь по функции `dopisz`, я исхожу из того что код выше нее менять нельзя. В `dopisz` вы должны выполнять три действия:

1. расширить массив указателей `lista.s` на один элемент
2. создать блок памяти для одной `slowo` и присвоить полученный указатель в конец `lista.s`
3. скопировать входное `slowo` во вновь созданное.

Действия 1 и 2 логично выделить в отдельную функцию:

```
slowo ** append_slowo(slowo ** l, int new_count)
{
    slowo ** newl = NULL;

    if(l && new_count > 1)
    {
        newl = (slowo **)realloc(l, sizeof(slowo*) * new_count);
    }
    else if(1 == new_count)
    {
        newl = (slowo **)malloc(sizeof(slowo*)); // создаем первый элемент
    }

    if(newl)
    {
        newl[new_count - 1] = (slowo *)malloc(sizeof(slowo));
    }

    return newl;        
}
```

Теперь функция `dopisz` примет следующий вид:

```
int dopisz(lista* L, slowo s) 
{
    L->s = append_slowo(L->s, L->n + 1);
    if(L->s && memcpy(L->s[L->n], &s))
    {
       ++L->n;
       L->jak_posortowana = BRAK;
       return 1;         
    }
    return 0;
}
```